# Functional construct for generating values based on previous value

Tags: java, groovy, functional-programming, generator

Let's say we have the following imperative snippet:

```
List list = new ArrayList()
var x = doSomething(arg1, ..., argN)
list.add(x)
do {
  x = doSomething(arg1, x.prop1, ..., x.propM, argN)
  list.add(x)
while (x.propK == <something>)
```

Similar how foldLeft can be used to sum values in an array, or how flatMap can generate new (sub)collections from existing one, does there exist a functional construct that will generate a collection of items, based on some generation function, possible initial value and termination function, with a signature similar to following:

```
def generate<U, T>(initialValue)(generator Function<U, T>, terminator Function<T, Boolean>)
```

Edit, an example:

```
generate({ "12345" }, { String s -> s.substring(1) }, { String s -> s.isEmpty })
```

should yield:

```
["12345", "2345", "345", "45", "5"]
```

Comment: Can you give an example with inputs and expected outputs

Comment: You can have a look at the `java.util.stream.Collectors` class, and use its methods in a construct like `someCollection.stream()...collect(Collectors. ...)`

Comment: if you know how to do it with java8 and like it, why not just do that?  groovy and java8 mix quite well.

Comment: @cfrick It's not that  can't do it via do-while, but I'd prefer learning more functional constructs and not reinvent the wheel by writing my own implementation (in production code). It is by chance that I'm currently diving into groovy, so in essence, I'm looking for a more language-agnostic approach I could reuse, for example, in Scala